# sql_cosntraints on exitsing field from original module

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-9

In product.template there is field default_code. Is it' possible to add sql_constraints that default code should be unique. Because this code doesn't work. Or do i need override default_code field in my costume module?

```
class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'


 _sql_constraints = [
    ('code_uniq', 'unique (default_code)', "Default code already exists!"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the constraint on model `product.product` because that's where this information (product reference) really is used. But `default_code` on `product.template` will only work since Odoo V10. In Odoo V8 and V9 it was a unstored related field, so not in DB. So you have to add the constraint on model `product.product`.

```py
class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('code_uniq', 'unique(default_code)', "Default code already exists!"),
    ]
```

Important to know: If the module, which sets up the constraint, is updated while the constraint will fail (e. g. the default_code actually twice in db), it won't create a sql constraint in db. So you have to clean up the data and update the module again or create the constraint in the db by yourself.

Comment: its interesting that this sql not showing warning message. in log i'm getting only 2018-06-22 09:13:48,434 25083 INFO test openerp.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "product_product" SET "default_code"='12',"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (11)

Comment: Oh i forgot to mention a thing. If this sql constraint is already broken on module update, odoo won't create it. This hint will be shown in the odoo logs. You have to clean up your data and either update your module again or create the constraint in db by yourself.

Comment: If the anwser is correct, then please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

- Please try with Python constrain may its useful for you :
- import this lines in python file :

  `from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError`
- Any write this method in your class :

  `@api.constrains('default_code')
  def _check_default_code(self):
      code = self.search([('default_code','=',self.default_code)])
      if len(code) > 1:
          raise ValidationError(_("Duplicate Record"))`